# How can I spread array elements into an object as the keys, and define some value for them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Let say I have an array:

```
const arr = ['a',  'b, 'c'];
```

I want to create an object like this:

```
{ 'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true}
```

How can I do this?

```
const obj = {...arr: true}
```

did not work

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution to close the question

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: true }), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that's not a valid assignment. The first way that comes to mind - if you want one of those cool ES6 one-liners - would be:

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((el) => [el, true]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.assign` and spread the array (with map).

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const res = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(key => ({[key]: true})));

console.log(res);
```